# Finding all polynomials up to a given degree to generate a bit sequence

Tags: random-number-generator, lfsr

Consider the following bit sequence:

00100000110

Using Berlekamp-Massey algorithm we can find the following minimal degree polynomial:

$P(x)=x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 1$

Now, is there a way to find all polynomials up to a given degree 8 that can generate the same bit sequence?

Comment: This is an interesting question. You could find higher degree polynomials by adding extra bits to your input sequence and brute forcing through their possible states.

Comment: Yes, that what I was thinking. But how do I know that how many extra bits I need to add to the sequence? For instance, the above example has 11 bits. Is it sufficient to add 5 more extra bits to get all polynomials up to degree 8? (And also it can not be an efficient method).

Comment: do you mean "generate the given finite sequence"? or generate any sequence of arbitrary length starting with that finite sequence?

Comment: Generate any sequence of arbitrary length starting with that (given) finite sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any finite sequence $(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{N-1})$ we may be interested in generating exactly that sequence, or generating the minimal degree (periodic) sequence which has that sequence as its' starting bits.

Trivially, the circulating shift register of length $L$, initially loaded by $(a_0,\ldots,a_{L-1})$, will generate this sequence, by implementing the recurrence

$$x_{t}=x_{t-L},\quad t\geq L,$$

i.e., give the characteristic polynomial $X^L+1.$

The polynomial that Berlekamp Massey (BM) yields is the minimal degree polynomial which matches this initial segment. Your sequence $$(a_0,\ldots,a_{10})=(00100000110)$$ has length $N=11$ and BM gave you a  degree $6$ polynomial.

In general, there will be a set of polynomials that can generate an initial segment. If the minimal recurrence (i.e., the minimal degree polynomial generating your sequence) has degree $n$, $2n$ bits are required to uniquely determine it. So to get a unique polynomial of degree 8 which generates a sequence, 16 bits are needed.

If you specify less than 16 bits, you will in general get more than one generating polynomial. You have 5 bits "free" to go from 11 to 16 bits so you may get up to 32 different polynomials, corresponding to all these possibilities, barring any linear dependencies in the resulting polynomials.

Comment: I have one doubt. How do we know that if we use 6 extra "free" bits instead of 5, it is going to give a polynomial 9 instead of 8. In other words, how we can be sure that we can cover all polynomials of degree 8 with added 5 "free" bits? Much appreciated!

Comment: In fact you don't, if you read my answer carefully. The "linear complexity" is the degree of the minimal polynomial, and if it is $n,$ then $2n$ is enough. The obvious thing to do is to track the degree obtained by BMA, and see if you need extra bits, based on the current degree.